# jquery using same animation on many elements, how to do best?

Tags: javascript, jquery

The animate functions does thre times exactly the same thing.
So how can I do this while writing `.animate(..` only once?
There should be an easy way but I couldn't figure out.

This is what I've got: [see fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CWs2r/)

```
$('.button').on('click',function(){
    $('header').animate({
        'left': '315px'
    }, 500, function() {
    });
    $('main').animate({
        'left': '315px'
    }, 500, function() {
    });
    $('footer').animate({
        'left': '315px'
    }, 500, function() {
    });
});
```

Comment: Are your callback functions also supposed to be the same?

Comment: just for your info you can always use CSS selectors with jquery, as group, nested, etc. selectors works perfectly with jquery.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi good question. Almost yes, I think I can figure out that myself. If not would there be an easy way of doing it?

Comment: @caramba, that depends, but you should be able to run different code based on the element passed to the callback (in `this`). It may not be as readable as three calls to `animate()` though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By using comma separated multiple selectors. This way:

```
$('header,main,footer').animate({
    'left': '315px'
}, 500, function() {
});
```

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CWs2r/1/)**

Comment: that's what I was looking for, I knew there must be an easy way. But didn't know it's that easy.. thank you! will accept as soon as I can